# What trim can I use on wooden stairs?

Tags: trim, stairs

We recently added wooden flooring to our stairs. I'm looking for a trim to add between the stairs and the wall. Something that I can cut easily and glue and then caulk. I'll need to edge it (rounded?) for the lip of the stairs and angle the inside to join up with the vertical. Is there anything made for this application?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I personally think adding trim will just draw more attention to the side of the stairs.  And no matter now nicely you trim it, it will stand out as people are not used to seeing trim on stairs.

In my opinion, I would just use caulk to fill the gap between the existing skirt and treads.  The gap looks pretty small and most people will never realize what you've done.

Edit:
I just realized...  There is no skirt board in those pictures.  You can add a skirt board after the fact but it is a very time consuming task.  See the link for an idea of how to do it.  http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/tips/scribing-a-skirtboard-to-an-existing-stair.aspx

Comment: Gotta go with diceless on this one. Stairs don't get trim like that in that way. What they get is a skirt board (see below) that's installed before the treads and risers. Just cut your loses. http://stairs4u.com/b/skirt_board.htm